# Change Firstname, Lastname label in customer registration in Magento2.1.7?

Tags: magento2, registration, labels

How to change label Firstname, Lastname only in Customer registration in Magento2.1.7?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this file **approx line number 63**

> vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/widget/name.phtml

you can override this to your theme file

> app/design/frontend/[Package]/[Theme]/Magento_Customer/templates/widget/name.phtml

Comment: please check it is working if its working please accpet